# Changing yAxis and plotOptions for drilldown

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I am using HighCharts to visualize percentages from projects, which are downdrilled into variables which make the percentages!

I will give my code :

```
$(function () {

    // Create the chart
    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Comparison'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                enabled: true,
                text: 'Percentages',
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'normal'
                }
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value}%'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.y:.1f}%'
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
        },
        series: [{
            name: '',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: []
        }],
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        drilldown: {
            series: [{
                name : '',
                id: '',
                data: []
            }]
        }
    };
    $.getJSON('/uploads/fraction.json', function (list) {
        options.series = list;

    });
    $.getJSON('/uploads/drilldown.json', function (list2) {
        options.drilldown.series = list2;
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
});
```

Example of the JSONs:

fraction.json

```
[{"name":"","colorByPoint":true,"data":[{"name":1,"y":80,"drilldown":1},{"name":2,"y":87,"drilldown":2},{"name":3,"y":105.71428571429,"drilldown":3},{"name":5,"y":"","drilldown":5},{"name":6,"y":53.160248409091,"drilldown":6}]}]
```

drilldown.json

```
[{"name":1,"id":1,"data":[["Total",2],["Estimated",2.5]]},{"name":2,"id":2,"data":[["Total",3.9],["Estimated",4.5]]},{"name":3,"id":3,"data":[["Total",3.7],["Estimated",3.5]]},{"name":5,"id":5,"data":[["Total",""],["Estimated",0.44]]},{"name":6,"id":6,"data":[["Total",0.233905093],["Estimated",0.44]]}]
```

I would like the graph to show percentages above the column and on the yAxis when the graph is first loaded, but absolute values when the drilldown is activated. I didn't manage to get it until now. Could you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways of doing those changes - a static and dynamic way. Static way - define data labels and tooltip options for drilldown series.

Dynamic way - apply the options on drilldown/drillup events.

```
events: {
    drilldown: function(options) {
      this.yAxis[0].update({
        labels: {
          format: '{value}'
        }
      }, false, false);

      options.seriesOptions.dataLabels = {
        format: '{point.y:.1f}'
      };

      options.seriesOptions.tooltip = {
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}</b> of total<br/>'
        };
    },
    drillup: function () {
        this.yAxis[0].update({
        labels: {
          format: '{value}%'
        }
      }, false, false);
    }
  }
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/d4fmaeea/

Two warnings:

1. In your json files, you have points which has value equals to "" which is not a valid type (must be number/null) and it may cause some issues, e.g. column with value 0 will have the same height as the column with value 10.
2. `$.getJSON()` is an asynchronous function. You use getJSON to assign `list` to `options.series` but that part may be executed after the chart was created so you would end up with the chart with no top-level series, only the drilldown ones.

Async part of code:

```
$.getJSON('/uploads/fraction.json', function (list) {
    options.series = list;

});
$.getJSON('/uploads/drilldown.json', function (list2) {
    options.drilldown.series = list2;
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the code! I will look at my code, with regards to your warnings. Cheers

Comment: Take my upvote!  Works over here.  Wish this was more apparent in the API docs for drilldown